# How to TEST Backup in ANDROID (perhaps using bmgr)

Tags: android, eclipse, backup

So I have implemented all the backup method following official android backup tutorial :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

But After I am done with everything, I cannot test it! The Android website says to use bmgr and use commands such as "adb shell bmgr run" etc, but I have no idea what this means...

I am using Eclipse to develop Android apps, and I am using real Samsung Galaxy Devices to test my apps. I am also backing up 1 file from the internal storage.

So how do I force the back up? Where can I write the command line (i can open DDMS)? What and where is this bmgr thing?

And does anyone know how long it takes for devices to actually backup data? Backing up data doesn't seem to happen immediately (if it happens at all) after you call:

```
BackupManager bm = new BackupManager(this);
bm.dataChanged();
```

TY

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem. You need to find adb.exe file in the Android ADK folder. It is inside platform-tools folder. And then you have to use terminal to go to the folder that has adb so that when you do ls, adb appears. Then you do the command but with ./ in the front

For example:

```
./adb shell bmgr run
```

instead of just adb shell bmgr run.

First check whether your device is connected using:
    ./adb device

From here you can force backup and restore for your app.